# Open a link from shell script

Tags: shell, scripting, putty

We are using PuTTY box to access the servers. We are on currently Windows 7 system.

Is there any way to open a link from the PuTTY box?

```
$ xdg-open http://www.example.com/
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://www.example.com/'
$ firefox -url http://www.google.com

(process:27541): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: no display specified
```

Both of these default commands are not working. As per my knowledge, I think these commands will work on a Linux system. Since I am on Windows and using a PuTTY box for scripting, is there any way for it?

Comment: Just to add up what I am trying:

I am searching a log file for the actions that are performed during the install/build. 
These testing environments have console that shows if all servers are up or not. 

I want to open a page for my team mates, after validating all "SUCCESSES" and no "FAILURES" in the logs.

Answer (score 2):

There is light weight browser you could use named [lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser)).

It will read full html and display it in console.

There is also wiki article about [alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_web_browser).

The normal browsers (GUI based) will fail as put don't have a way of transporting the visual content from the accessed machine to your PC.

Comment: Well, I am on a company's network. Don't have the administrative rights to install/uninstall anything. So, may be this wont work for me. 
*Does that mean there is no workaround?

Comment: it depends on the environment, if you have the access to the machine from your own home machine then you can install xterm which has the support for graphical display and you should be able to open normal browser through it.

Comment: Also you can get the raw html using wget command with the webpage link, it will download the html page, so for instance if you want to just copy some text from it it will help you...

Comment: @cerkiewny This may help. Checking on it and replying with the outcomes.

Comment: Didn't help. It's basically downloading the source code of the page.

Comment: Yes. thats exactly what I meant :) can you install something on the linux machine then?

Comment: No, I guess. I wished there would be a command that could simply open a link www.google.com in my browser. The problem is may be because I'm using Putty and not a complete Linux system.

Comment: there is , its called lynx. The other things require the x server to connect to, this is the program that runs the graphical environment. So either you need to install the xterm on your windows, allowing the graphical connection to linux, then run the firefox, or install any of the command line browsers on linux and access the webpage via putty. To install lynx type apt-get install lynx in your putty and you are good to go.

Comment: Okay, Dropping a mail to the administration and see if they agree for an installation

Thank you very much guys..

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to open the link in your default Windows browser.

You cannot do with with PuTTY.

Though some PuTTY clones support recognizing links in the console output and allows you to click them to open the link in a local browser.

For example KiTTY allows that:
https://www.9bis.net/kitty/#!pages/URLHyperlinks.md

KiTTY is portable, so you do not need to install it.

Answer (score 0):

This is run from the remote computer (to which PuTTY connects):

```
$ xdg-open http://www.example.com/
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 461: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
```

Although links2, etc., may be *found* on a Linux system, generally none are installed by default.  The commands for installing differ from one type of system to another, and are off-topic (perhaps in superuser).